# Is it possible to write a recursive chunk function?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write a recursive chunk function? If not, why not?

I don't need this function I'm just trying to understand recursion and write my own functions that use the concept. If I can't use recursion to solve this problem, what makes recursion the wrong tool for the job in this case and others?

```
    function chunk(array, size) {
      if (array.length === 0) {
        return array;
      } else {
        return [array.slice(0, size), chunk(array.slice(size),size)];
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking to flatten the result? Just spread the recursive call

Comment: You haven't mentioned what the problem you want to solve is.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is that really your question?

Comment: Since `chunk` returns an array, you should probably `concat` the result of chunk if you don't want a deeply-nested result.

Comment: To clarify. My problem was that my recursive solution kept returning nested arrays  instead of a flat array of arrays of fixed length. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you are trying to achieve something like this

```
function chunk(array, size) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return array;
  } else {
    return [array.slice(0, size)].concat(chunk(array.slice(size),size));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns an array with the first chunked array and then nested arrays for each further chunk.

```
return [array.slice(0, size), chunk(array.slice(size), size)];
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The mentioned part need to be lifted one array level. This could be done by the use of the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in front of `chunk`.

```js
function chunk(array, size) {
    return array.length
        ? [array.slice(0, size), ...chunk(array.slice(size), size)]
        : [];
}

console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```